# How do I maintain a string linebreak through a PlayerPref?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am printing code to a TextMesh, and it is always changing.  I need to save the string to a `PlayerPref`, so that I can load it back up.  In order to get the text to fit properly, I have to force a line break in the string, using `\n`.

```
string text = "line1\nline2";

PlayerPref.SetString("Text", text);
LocationSide1.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Text");
```

If I set the text without the `PlayerPref` it will do a line break:

```
  line1
  line2
```

With the `PlayerPref` it prints as one line:

```
 line1\nline2
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the '\' is escaped.

Have you tried to unescape the string ?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

[...]

string text = "line1\nline2";

PlayerPref.SetString("Text", text);
LocationSide1.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = Regex.Unescape(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Text"));
myString = Regex.Unescape(myString);
```